# Why does this Promise time out?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm working on a Telegram bot. I am trying to create a way to wait for a user response using the promises, but the promise I created to accomplish this hangs and times out.

The code for the Telegram command handler sends a few messages and registers a handler function for the reply event:

```js
export default async function (ctx: BacchusContext): Promise<void> {

    if(!ctx.isAdmin){
        await ctx.reply('You are not a recognized administrator. You can\'t use this command.');
        return;
    }

    await ctx.reply('Alright, so we\'re adding a party. Cool. When is it?');

    const rep = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ctx.onReply( resolve);
    });

    await ctx.reply(`On Reply: ${rep}`);
    
}
```

The registration of the reply event handler is shown below. The function passed to `onReply` is saved in a session object independent of the telegram context (a static class member):

```js
    private static middleware_reply() {
        return (ctx: BacchusContext, next) => {

            ctx.onReply = (fcn: (rCtx) => void | Promise<void>) => {
                ctx.setSessionData<(replyCtx) => void | Promise<void>>('onReply', fcn);
            };

            ctx.waitForReply = () => {
                return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
                    ctx.setSessionData<(replyCtx) => void | Promise<void>>('onReply', (replyCtx) => {
                        return resolve(replyCtx.message.text);
                    });
                });

            };

            return next();
        };
    }
```

As soon as the user sends a text message to the bot, the code checks if a `onReply` handler was defined for the current session, and if it was it will be executed and then removed. The event handler is only supposed to fire once.

```js
        this.bot.on('text', (ctx: BacchusContext, next) => {
            const handler = ctx.getSessionData<(replyCtx) => Promise<void>>('onReply');
            if(handler){
                debug('Executing reply function');
                handler(ctx);
                // Delete handler
                ctx.setSessionData<(replyCtx) => Promise<void>>('onReply', null);
            }
            return next();
        });
```

The code so far makes sense to me, but I keep getting the following error:

```
 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] Promise timed out after 90000 milliseconds                                                                                                                                                       14:38:55  

  at Timeout._onTimeout (node_modules\p-timeout\index.js:39:64)
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
  at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Why does this promise time out?

EDIT:
What's weird about this code is that the following code works fine:

```js
    ctx.onReply(async (replyCtx) => {
        await ctx.reply(`On Reply: ${replyCtx.message.text}`);
    });
```

So the callback function works fine, but as soon as it is 'promisified' it stops working. Why could that be?

Comment: I don't know what `BacchusContext` is so it is hard to tell what you do wrong. `What's weird about this code is that the following code works fine:` that indicates, that in some cases the callback passed to `ctx.onReply` is not called (maybe an error happened which you don't handle?). `So the callback function works fine` yes but you assume that it is guaranteed to be called, but your problem description indicates that this is not the case.

Comment: Have you tried to google the error already? There is a related github issue: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1479

Comment: This looks odd `fcn: (rCtx) => void | Promise<void>`. Why not have `fcn` always be async, i.e. return a Promise? Otherwise you're unleashing zalgo https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/.

Comment: @t.niese Yes that's true. Debugging the code I have found that when the promise is used, the event handler in `this.bot.on('text', eventHandler())` is not called, so `onReply` is also not called. Does this mean that my promise is somehow blocking the main thread?

Comment: @morganney I have changed all the signatures in the code to `Promise<void>` as suggested. It hasn't fixed the problem, but I agree that it makes more sense.

Comment: It does not block the thread, but it is „blocking“ the promise chain it participates in because it does not resolve. At some point in your code you use `p-timeout` to wrap the Promise returned from `export default async function (ctx: BacchusContext): Promise<void>` or one in which that promise is used. But as the returned Promise does not resolve the timeout kicks in. If you wrap eventbased or callback based code into a promise you have to ensure it resolves or rejects at some point.